# issue with the query getting the same line id but the line id is different

Tags: mysql

I have ran the below query to get the different lineId's but it is displaying the same lineId's.I could not find the problem where the problem in the query.Please check the below query and

Please suggest me to solve the problem.

query:

```
SELECT
    item.id AS itemId,
    ol.id AS lineId,
    l.description AS order_description,
    l.type_id AS itemType,
    l.quantity,
    l.amount AS amount
FROM
    invoice_line l, purchase_order po, order_line ol,
    order_process op, item,invoice i,item_type it,item_type_map itm
WHERE
    i.id = l.invoice_id AND
    op.invoice_id = l.invoice_id AND
    op.order_id = po.id AND
    po.id = ol.order_id AND
    l.invoice_id = 10325 AND
    ol.item_id = itm.item_id AND 
    itm.type_id = it.id AND
    l.item_id = item.id AND
    item.id = itm.item_id AND
    it.description <> 'Provisionable' AND
    it.description <> 'Usage' AND
    it.description <> 'Refund' AND
    NOT l.description = "voice call" AND
    it.id = 280500
GROUP BY
    it.id,
    l.description,
    l.id;
```

[image]

Comment: Your query is invalid, because you only group by three columns, but you select many more than this.  I would recommend reading a good MySQL tutorial on `GROUP BY`, to understand how it works.

Comment: how many columns i need to add in group by

Comment: When I add more columns in GROUP BY is it is going to 43 rows,with the above query result is only 8 rows.please suggest me.

Comment: The group by is forcing the lined id to be the same and is indeterminate. Group by is designed to work with aggregation functions - you don't have any. You should change the implicit joins to explicit joins and change the join order to make it clearer what the flow of data is. I suspect it is items>>orders>>invoices. It would also help the question if you stated what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: how to do explicity.please suggest me

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what you want to do here but I would start by rewriting the query to make it more understandable and I would rebuild by adding the joins and conditions a bit at a time so I understand what is happening at each step.

```
SELECT
    item.id AS itemId,
    ol.id AS lineId,
    l.description AS order_description,
    l.type_id AS itemType,
    l.quantity,
    l.amount AS amount
FROM        item
join        item_type it item.id = itm.item_id
join        item_type_map itm itm.type_id = it.id
left join       order_process op op.order_id = po.id
left join       order_line ol ol.item_id = itm.item_id
left join       purchase_order po po.id = ol.order_id
left join       invoice i op.invoice_id = l.invoice_id
left join       invoice_line l l.item_id = item.id

WHERE
    i.id = l.invoice_id AND #????
    l.invoice_id = 10325 AND
    it.description <> 'Provisionable' AND
    it.description <> 'Usage' AND
    it.description <> 'Refund' AND
    l.description <> 'voice call' AND
    it.id = 280500
```

I have assumed there is a 1 to 1 relationship between item,item_type and item_type_map. But after that I have no idea about the relationships to the other tables. It would help if you could add sample data from all these tables as text to your question. I didn't understand *NOT l.description = "voice call"* so I changed it and I removed the group by because I don't know what result you want.

Comment: I need as in the image but lineId column should not be same id's it has to be different.